# Subsetting with 2 conditions not working with which function

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I have been trying to find a similar issue on Stackoverflow but all the similar questions still do not answer my question or resolve this issue.

I have this data set where, using `which()` and other functions, I am trying to find the id's for which both conditions are true. However, I can't figure out how to get this to work in R. It either returns all the id's or  an empty vector with what I have tried so far.

So I sampled 20 observations from my data just for this question (the actual data frame is huge), to produce a mock sample to communicate my problem and resolve it on Stackoverflow but I'll try.

I have this data frame and I want the id's that contain strictly both attachment V and attachment R.

```
df
          id attachment 
271  1000534          V      
372  1000547          V      
1012 1000530          R      
1568 1000539          R     
1095 1000530          R      
185  1000534          V      
1476 1000539          R      
903  1000530          R      
309  1000547          V      
1010 1000530          R      
333  1000547          V      
1094 1000530          R      
1334 1000539          R      
340  1000547          V      
730  1000530          R      
22   1000067          V     
1308 1000533          R      
799  1000530          R      
138  1000533          V      
1161 1000530          R
```

So, as we see, the id 1000533 has both V and R, so that's the kind of id I want to catch that has both and I tried the following options:

```
VR <- df[(df$attachment == 'V') & (df$attachment == 'R'),]
VR <- df[(df$attachment == 'V') && (df$attachment == 'R'),]
VR <- df[which(df$attachment == 'V') && which(df$attachment == 'R'),]
VR <- df[which(df$attachment == 'V') & which(df$attachment == 'R'),]
```

but they return a dataframe with all 20 values. When I call

```
unique(VR$id)
```

it returns all the id's from the initial dataframe. With my actual data, it returns an empty dataframe, depending on which of the above subsetting attempts I try but it never returns what I want - a dataframe only with id's (or observations) that contain both attachment V and attachment R.

What am I doing wrong and how to extract only those id's that have both, V and R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each observation has only one "attachment" level, it is impossible for any to have both V and R.

As the IDs are repeated across observations, you can use `intersect` to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
myIds <- intersect(df$id[df$attachment == "V"], df$id[df$attachment == "R"])
```

Now myIds will store the ids that have both a V and an R.

```
myIds
[1] 1000533
```

which is a single id in the example.

---

If you want observations that only have V attachment and not R attachment, you could use `setdiff` instead of `intersect`:

```
myIds <- setdiff(df$id[df$attachment == "V"], df$id[df$attachment == "R"])
```

One thing to note here is that intersect is commutative, so that it doesn't matter which order you feed the arguments. For `setdiff`, order matters. You can read the order as the elements of argument 1 that are not in argument 2.

Comment: Wow!That worked!I've been struggling for so long with this,thank you so much! I have another question: how would you recommend to subset strictly for V attachment?

Comment: @Imo In my comment I meant to ask if I want only attachment V, would `df[which(df$attachment == 'V') ,] ` suffice?

Comment: Yes, that code would provide all observations with a V attachment. I've added a slightly more complicated answer, which is all ids that have a v attachment, but not an R attachment.

Comment: @Imo thank you!So in `setdiff` the first argument inside the function will catch all the ones with the V's but the second argument will exclude all the one's which have both V & R?

Answer (score 2):

@Imo solution's is certainly the most compact. 
The following is a variant using `reshape2`. It has the perk of offering extra info about how many times each ID/attachment combination appears:

```
library(reshape2)
output <- dcast(df, id ~ attachment)

output
  id      R V
1 1000067 0 1
2 1000530 8 0
3 1000533 1 1
4 1000534 0 2
5 1000539 3 0
6 1000547 0 4
```

To find the ids with both attachments:

```
output$id[output$R != 0 & output$V != 0]
[1] 1000533
```

To see which IDs have attachment V and not R:

```
output$id[output$R == 0 & output$V != 0]
```

To see which IDs have attachment R and not V:

```
output$id[output$R != 0 & output$V == 0]
```

Comment: Note that the starting part is, essentially, `table(df)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(a = sort(paste0(unique(attachment), collapse = "")))
```

which returns this:

```
        id attachment     a
     <int>     <fctr> <chr>
1  1000534          V     V
2  1000547          V     V
3  1000530          R     R
4  1000539          R     R
5  1000530          R     R
6  1000534          V     V
7  1000539          R     R
8  1000530          R     R
9  1000547          V     V
10 1000530          R     R
11 1000547          V     V
12 1000530          R     R
13 1000539          R     R
14 1000547          V     V
15 1000530          R     R
16 1000067          V     V
17 1000533          R    RV
18 1000530          R     R
19 1000533          V    RV
20 1000530          R     R
```

Now you can `filter` by the column `a` for whatever condition you like. In this case, to get only `ids` that have `V` and `R`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(a = sort(paste0(unique(attachment), collapse = ""))) %>%
  filter(a == "RV") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(id)
```

You can change the filter condition to only look for `V` or anything else.